# Intellisense underlines UDF name in red but it still works

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have several UDFs defined and they work as expected, but intellisense, wherever they are used, underlines them in red and says "Cannot find either column dbo or the user defined function or aggregate." The functions work, they are simply not being recognized by intellisense. Any way of making intellisense recognize them?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Refresh the intellisense cache](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/07/04/sql-server-how-to-refresh-ssms-intellisense-cache-to-update-schema-changes/) by pressing the following key combination: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

You can try to refresh the local cache for IntelliSense. Do this by going to Edit > IntelliSense  > Refresh Local Cache.

Answer (score -2):

Did you just create the UDFs?
You may need to refresh the Intellisense(if you don't know how, just quit SSMS and open it again)